# Typescript: 'string' can't be used to index type on complex object

Tags: typescript

I've got this complex object

```
const classes = {
  Barbarian: {
    armorAndWeoponProficianies: [
      'lightAmour',
      'mediumArmour',
      'Sheilds',
      'simpleWeopons',
      'martialWeopons',
    ],
    class: 'Barbarian',
    description:
      'A fierce warrior of primitive background who can enter a battle rage',
    hitDie: '1d12',
    primaryAbility: 'STR',
    savingThrowProficianies: ['STR', 'CON'],
  },
  Bard: {
    armorAndWeoponProficianies: [
      'lightArmor',
      'simpleWeapons',
      'handCrossbows',
      'longswords',
      'rapiers',
      'shortswords',
    ],
    class: 'Bard',
    description:
      'An inspiring magician whose power echoes the music of creation',
    hitDie: '1d8',
    primaryAbility: 'CHA',
    savingThrowProficianies: ['DEX', 'CHA'],
  },
}
```

and here I want to use the argument classType as a key but TypeScript doesnt like it

```
  const hitPointGenerator = (classType: string) => {
    const selectedClass = classes[classType].hitDie;
//                                  ^ Error
    console.log(selectedClass)
  };
```

and the error i get is

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ Barbarian: { armorAndWeoponProficianies: string[]; class: string; description: string; hitDie: string; primaryAbility: string; savingThrowProficianies: string[]; }; Bard: { armorAndWeoponProficianies: string[]; ... 4 more ...; savingThrowProficianies: string[]; }; ... 9 more ...; Wizzard: { ...; }; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ Barbarian: { armorAndWeoponProficianies: string[]; class: string; description: string; hitDie: string; primaryAbility: string; savingThrowProficianies: string[]; }; Bard: { armorAndWeoponProficianies: string[]; ... 4 more ...; savingThrowProficianies: string[]; }; ... 9 more ...; Wizzard: { ...; }; }'.ts(7053)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different ways to tackle the problem:

## Use correct type

Change the `classType` parameter to `keyof typeof classes`

```
const hitPointGenerator = (classType: keyof typeof classes) => {
    const selectedClass = classes[classType].hitDie;
    console.log(selectedClass)
};
```

This has the advantage that you cannot accidentially call it with a wrong key, e.g.

```
hitPointGenerator('Bard'); // OK
hitPointGenerator('Bart'); // compile error - notice the 't' at the end
```

[TypeScript Playground Example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=37&ssc=39&pln=37&pc=59#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-gCoECCQAJTiQ6Gw+GIlXsiPyRRY9S3ACiAA08ep8a2yfEKXg8HO8AB6JdwDikPPAWCNoTdYZkbQObZQPCgSCwYuiECwqAAcW2HQLg2wAAonRAQd9dww5qhvsMd0EHN33QABKLAAD5GDyWJYDQSIt1sfEkBQLA4BQtAICUd9P13LIADpi1LABuJgzwgEBInwzVtBfeCE12eUMNAhdSLwS9rx2e8wEfKAOBfYoyB4dRQNIjib243j+MEq0ROImAVxgeQujXcI-G6DoJFIABCPAgA)

When you hoover the mouse over the `classType` parameter in typescript-playground you can see the type is `"Barbarian" | "Beard"`: this is a [Union Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types), in this case a subtype of `string` (i.e. it is more specific)

## Use string index signature

```
const classes: {
        [key: string]: any;
} = {
  Barbarian: {
  ...
```

[TypeScript Playground Example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=2&ssc=14&pln=4&pc=2#code/PTAEHcFNQVwZ2gQwHagJbICaQB6jmgObKIAuMATtKQPaimQA2j9AngA6RwDGFa7pegAsyoANaRWcUDQBmbTvlJ9khUIirrmNKJgBQ3GsjiDujRHARwAXKADee0KADaE1rZMrCAXVspWANx6AL6gALz2jqAAQhoARhpoKLYOTk4aALY0FACCWADqkDTsRgAKFHJo3EnIaFy2zlFpoADkjERCpDlZlC0ANE1pLRmQmGgwGTkUPRT9g04tAMpCkGiMmHBzzQsEGeyMkIXFRpsD260ZGqRJjEclxltp3mdpZhY2rbEUCXwoj07YHh8ARoIzWeatHKgWR1CjcaDgDR8bIyeTsPgZNDXABu0AS3DEhAqMCwECEdG4KFAkGQDAo6lACVIpAOoAoiEIkH+oCEWIAInVbC0AIyYYUAJm56LQlworBycTWWPcrUWABUAErcuCIbEYQhqoQVcDlSrVFB1D7OJaa-qtADCAHkAHItZ5RYIvL6YFKDTLZPKYO5lCow821eouCFtDpdabZbk7GX7Q6QRD3U7RkRYe0VSxxHSZ85tIyEODgbIbROtdnsWFF7YtODkiikcuVhtOd3NN6WIXe7mA3j8a5g6N5dDGOteUCXQhVGpkmgIUAlKD0yDcclcYTQDLwKqo0C8NOj5Dc3mkAWQIWigAcUoxGnlivapBVLXtAAkctrdfrDWNU0wxqS0GhaPkAFEAA07U-H83ReYI9BCFDDGMQRL1KGgMFIABxGlIHZWh6QiAAKXs4DVDgbyULwAEpwgAPkiJx0JMfAmE3BhMHtcxLHCY9+KsZxKOozhvAAOkva8gjYk4aAOSTGBoQgyIQA5uB4vj3nokIgj0LCcNpAjkCIshsjIloB3ooIjNw0zzJIqyvlIFpbNAEBQGdR1jxoPY1mgIiKgoABCPQgA)

With this string index signature, you can add new items dynamically to the `classes` object:

```
classes['new'] = {
  ...
}
```

more info on [index-signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html)

### index signature with interface

To also use types for the values, you can define an interface, e.g.:

```
interface IMember {
  armorAndWeoponProficianies: string[];
  class: string;
  description: string;
  hitDie: string;
  primaryAbility: string;
  savingThrowProficianies: string[];
}

// we use an index signature to tell typescript that keys of type string are allowed
const classes: {
  [key: string]: IMember;
} = {
...
}
```

[TypeScript Playground Example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=52&ssc=17&pln=52&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFkIFsBG1kDeAUMsnFFgPZQCCIAJgOoSUAOlIAClJTMAsDghgEAM4AuZKLBRQAcwDaAXQDcJZAgA2cURKkz5a0vTEJZrMMA6TpskHKPIAFsDAARETYP3HrWVnIATxocYE1XQK87B3VROAA3eQAVJx4Ad25efkFhMSj5ZTUAXyIiAHoy5DSUAFdRFCFkUBMADylgORA4MBqoFDBKZEhNTSHA1lNzMCGnbuQAawhA0WReMYn9aLI+shHKavoiBA5pDW1dPMJ1BUXIzfklSQxsPChi5ABeK9IAIXIccg5STEUikchUWgMZhsDiZPgCIQiPQKdSg5AAcnCcicYBoVF66IANKjQeisBB6MAalgaBRKATiWjSOiAMpOCBheiiIkk5miYBYViaCDQ9ggbmMplk8iWOCaUUnHlopSS0haHR6dF-KAA2RCJWgkyiMzACxWEDiXkYmjIPjQJBVciyairGDIPwC1zAeIoAEIeZyHg1BhVJyDBCNCDgfBwZAAsBgYXIKBwOQQA2kFzuTwYgCM9FzACYM+7-EEQmEIpJWUkAEoluKJewpdJw7KIy4KGv1wkYgDCAHkAHLolXqIqS7X0YEk8HUOhMFhitsI3LIq2Yjo42kQkt8gVCkUQOBiiUb2YMPs8XQ4fZnpkYzQcOSiNLULl7jEp1giKD3qWiGGUBgK+77-qQY5ouqujVlOJZGiaZrWBudBNOKP5bAEcjtiAoaUPU7r7PgEAIGGYgzCgWB1PwroaH03TmiWWYeBA1b5gAHCWHoBFAwShOEYB3OifYABI0A2CTJKk+wrjkSKSF2bgAKIABpEv2YmjpKJREDpxzitMWacJQoBgAA4lG0DdC6XwABTQaISTjKx9z2AAlJ8AB83waCc0z1MKCCQPQfbnCsXwOWICgOU5ExKAAdMxIiOPpoiUMK8VPnItkBSRwWhRqbm6WoRBGSZ4AWSAVkDFAtlauQ9Dom5ahlaZlXVdQdXamATUqMgFTIEOA6+YKYQoNAPBQAAhEQQA)

## Cast to any

```
  const hitPointGenerator3 = (classType: string) => {
    const selectedClass = (classes as any)[classType].hitDie;
//                                  ^ cast
    console.log(selectedClass)
  };
```

This is just for the sake of completion: I'd avoid this.

[TypeScript Playground Example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=37&ssc=24&pln=37&pc=41#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-gCoECCQAJTiQ6Gw+GIlXsiPyRRY9S3ACiAA08ep8a2yfEKXg8HO8KBILBi6IQLCoABxbYdAuDbAACidEBB3yEZZg0GD2gAlFgAHyMPKxWBoSLAXbypAoLAwY8-mgGDICwYDfLeSgnmeF5ZAAdMWpYANx4AA9Ch6oYZhWEwAAenh+EALQbNAKbrLQ3wAIRMMuEAgJEsGatoh7vgmX74oBt4Lsh85rhuOw7mAe5QBwh7FGQPDqLeyG8ZuAlCSJYlWpJiEwGhMDEoSIJwCA4R+N0HQSKQVFAA)

## Disable `noImplicitAny`

Disable the `noImplicitAny` option in your `tsconfig.json` - [ref](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

This can be useful when you migrate some javascript code to typescript: I would not use it for new project and try to activate `noImplicitAny` whenever possible

[TypeScript Playground Example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?noImplicitAny=false&ssl=36&ssc=51&pln=36&pc=1#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-gCoECCQAJTiQ6Gw+GIlXsiPyRRY9S3ACiAA08ep8a2yfEKXg8HO8AB6JcwYmEkHDhgAAzAIAAkmK0QYwN9t-6MHYoeRIjx-WAU2n8eBpNo8KBILBi6IQLCoABxbYOgLQZsAACidCAQW+IQyxgaBg20ABKLAAD5GDyWJYDQSJgF2eUkBQLA4EItAICUSDoNgrIADpi1LABuJgPwgEBIhozVtDAnCE3w-FSKQhcmPnb9fx2QCwGAqAODA4oyB4dQkKY0S-wkqSZLkq1FIYmAVzXQk4BAcI-G6DoJFIABCPAgA)

Comment: using the string index signature, how would I avoid using `any`?

Comment: you define an interface, I've updated my answer, see `index signature with interface`

Comment: I've bookmarked your answer I'm going to be coming back to this allot for a while, thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because there are only two valid keys for `classes`, but string could be literally any string.

Maybe try changing your function signature to;

```
const hitPointGenerator = (classType: keyof typeof classes) => {
    const selectedClass = classes[classType].hitDie;
    console.log(selectedClass)
  };
```

so that only `"Barbarian" | "Bard"` are valid inputs for classType

Comment: ben your solution works great, can you recommend any reading where I can understand this more, I keep coming up against this indexing issue